# Why does VB.NET behave like this with lists?

Tags: vb.net, list, nested-lists

This is a question concerning a list of lists.

```
    Dim smallList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim largeList As New List(Of List(Of Integer))

    smallList.Add(3)
    largeList.Add(smallList)
    smallList.Clear()
    smallList.Add(4)
    largeList.Add(smallList)
```

In this code, I would expect largeList to add the list (3) to itself, and then to add the list (4) to itself. But instead of storing the data inside smallList, it seems to store a reference smallList instead, so ends up containing ((4), (4)), which is not what I want.

Why does it do this, and how can I get around it? Thanks.

Comment: Check your favorite .NET programming book about the difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a list of reference types, you actually have a list of references. Adding something to the list doesn't mean that the data is copied, it's just the reference that is added to the list.

To add separate objects to the list, you have to create a new object for each item, and as lists are reference types themselves, that goes for lists too.

```
Dim smallList As List(Of Integer) ' just a reference at this time
Dim largeList As New List(Of List(Of Integer))

smallList = New List(Of Integer)() ' The first list
smallList.Add(3)
largeList.Add(smallList)
smallList = New List(Of Integer)() ' Here's another list
smallList.Add(4)
largeList.Add(smallList)
```